# concatenate image and video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, images

I have 1 image and 1 video that I would like to concatenate
I tried to resize the image and the video to the samesize using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -vf scale=432:432 -strict -2 image_out.jpg
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=432:432 -strict -2 video_out.jpg
```

after resizing the image and video. I run the command to concatenate them:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image_out.jpg -i video_out.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" out.mp4
```

but received error:

> [Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x3850cc0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 432x432, SAR 4:3) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (432x432, SAR 1:1)
>   [Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x3850cc0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
>   Error reinitializing filters!
>   Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
>   Conversion failed!

I think there is something wrong with the resizing command but I don't know how to make it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=432:432,setsar=1[im];[1]scale=432:432,setsar=1[vid];[im][vid]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" out.mp4
```

Video streams have a Sample Aspect Ratio. Video players resize the width during playback by multiplying the stored width by this number. The concat filter requires inputs to have the same SAR. I've added the setsar filter to keep the same SAR for both inputs.

Comment: thank you. it works perfectly! I am wondering if I can use mp3 audio with the image. So that the image will be displayed with audio in the first 10s, and then the video will be playbacked?